# Prometheus: How to create alerts based on the result of any Airflow Dag instead of a specific Airflow Dag

Tags: airflow, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I installed airflow[statsd] using "pip install 'apache-airflow[statsd]' and I installed statsd_exporter. Now I can see airflow metrics from Prometheus. but all the metrics related to airflow have dag_id and task_id as a part of metrics names.

For example, for dag id "dag1" with task id "task1" the metrics for the time taken to finish a task is: airflow_dag_dag1_task1_duration. For dag id "dag2" with task id "task2" the metrics is: airflow_dag_dag2_task2_duration.

what I am interested is something like: trigger an alert if any dag fails, or trigger an alert if it takes more than XXX sec for a dag to complete. in another word, I do not want to create a rule and alert for each individual dag or task. I want to alert the generic situation.

How can I create rule/alert in Prometheus for generic case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use something like the below and base your alerting off that:

```
{__name__=~"airflow_dag.+_duration"}
```

Be warned though, if you use just `{__name__=~".+"}` it's an expensive query and could potentially break the instance requiring a restart of the Prometheus service.

Updated to include example alert:

```
- alert: Saf_Test
  expr: ({__name__=~"windows_cpu.+_total"} > 5.8281319e+07)
  for: 5m
  labels:
    severity: warning
  annotations:
    description: 'Alert text here'
    summary: 'Summary here'
```

Comment: Thanks Saf. do you mean I can write it in rules yaml file at prometheus server like here? https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/. your code looks like python code not rules so I am not sure if I understand what you mean. can you give me an example how to implement an alerting rule using your solution?

Comment: Sure thing, I've added an example alert I've tested on my instance. Hopefully that gives you something you can modify for your needs.

Comment: Thank you Saf. that is the new thing to me. I will verify and let you know.

Comment: Hi Saf. and you said this will eat CPU of prometheus server? I guess prometheus has no clue but just blindly parse the raw word that may be the reason. but I feel my use case is very common. Is there a solution to make prometheus query efficiently?  the airflow metrics I get is not created by me so I have no way to move dag/task from metrics name to label.

Comment: I meant more if you just do ```{__name__=~".+"}``` - because that will list everything, as long as you set the regex to limit your search you should be good

Comment: Thanks Saf then I am safe. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Hi, Saf: I tried and this expression works. but when it fires alert it did not show which dag leads to the alert. how can I get this information? the use case is: we want to get alert if any dag has issue.And then we can troubleshoot that dag.

Comment: Hi, Saf, I think I have a way to know which dag. when I goto alert, click the expression of ({__name__=~"windows_cpu.+_total"} > 5.8281319e+07), then all the related dags are listed, then I will know which dags I should troubleshoot. Thanks